# How to update variable columns based on json object from body? (C# web api, LINQ to SQL)

Tags: c#, json, linq, asp.net-web-api, crud

So right now I can update a record using this code:

```
//POST: api/Cicmpies/testname
        [HttpPost("{cmp_name}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateCicmpy([FromRoute] string cmp_name, [FromBody] Cicmpy cicmpy)
        {
            var cicmpyUpdated = await
                                (from c in _context.Cicmpy
                                 where c.CmpName.Equals(cmp_name)
                                 select c).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

            cicmpyUpdated.CmpCode = cicmpy.CmpCode;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok(cicmpy);
        }
```

To achieve this I send a json object using Postman like this:

```
{
        "cmpCode": "testcodeupdated333"
}
```

To the following URL:

```
http://localhost:54488/api/Cicmpies/testname
```

This works since I know I'll only have to update "CmpCode" so I can do:

```
cicmpyUpdated.CmpCode = cicmpy.CmpCode;
```

What if I don't know what values will have to be updated? So sometimes the json object can contain 1 key-value pair (CmpCode), but sometimes it can contain 4, sometimes all 20, etc... How can I ensure "cicmpyUpdated" will always set all the values from howmany key-value pairs you entered in your json object?

Answer (score 0):

you can do 3 things: 
1.- use default values. Give some default values and then update everything
2.- set a maximum of n pairs per object and then send several objects.
3.- keep checking: example: while (more pairs){do whatever}

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the proper way to handle this is to establish a “ViewModel” class for your input parameter on your action method. One option is to give your viewmodel the same properties of your entity and make those viewmodel properties nullable so that if the input doesn’t provide a value you can add a check in your controller to avoid setting the model property if the input viewmodel property is null. Alternatively you could add a custom model binder to set additional properties on your viewmodel that tell you which fields were present in the Json data.